# Parse nginx access log and extract IP, detect geo location for each parsed IP

Tags: bash, curl, nginx, geolocation

I have question about parsing nginx access log,

have error  in this code `<<< grep "pagename" <<< "$line0"`

not work  `grep "pagename"`

```
while IFS= read -r line0
do    
ipList=$( grep -oP '\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}))\b'
<<< grep "pagename" <<< "$line0")
for oneIP in $ipList
do
    curl -s  "http://ipinfo.io/$oneIP"
done

done < /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

Thanks.

Comment: it works for me, what is your error message?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `<<< grep "pagename" <<< "$line0"` is slighly off, `<<<X` inputs the 
string X to the stdin.

The syntax you want is the process substitution syntax (combined with a redirection-arrow):

`< <(grep "pagename" <<< "$line0")`

Here's also a simpler solution:

```
#! /bin/bash
while read -r oneIP; do
    curl -s "http://ipinfo.io/$oneIP"
done < <(grep "pagename" /var/log/nginx/access.log \
         | grep -oP '\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}))\b')
```

The result of the first `grep` is piped to the second, and that stream of ips is then redirected to the `while`-loop which runs the curl for each of the ips.

You could also parallelize this with something like [gnu parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
#! /bin/bash
grep "pagename" /var/log/nginx/access.log \
| grep -oP '\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}))\b' \
| parallel echo curl -s "http://ipinfo.io/"{}
```